# Copy/Cut/Paste event_generate not working

Tags: tkinter

In a Listbox I am trying to use copy/cut/paste from a right-click menu that has Cut/Copy/Paste/Delete/SelectAll. I have been able to get the SelectAll and Delete to work but I my code doesn't work for Copy/Cut/Paste. Can someone modify the code to show me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def selectall_text():
    lb.event_generate("<SelectAll>")

def copy_text():
    lb.event_generate("<Copy>")  

m = tk.Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
m.add_command(label ="Copy", command=copy_text))
m.add_command(label ="SelectAll", command=selectall_text)
m.add_separator()
m.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    
lb = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode="multiple")

for i in range(10): lb.insert(tk.END, i)
lb.pack()
   
def show_menu(event):
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()   

lb.bind("<Button-3>", show_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with it, but you don't need parenthesis around the event. THe event is a string: `lb.event_generate("<<Copy>>")`

Comment: I removed the parenthesis around the event but you are correct, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Hopefully someone can correct me if I'm wrong but after changing the Listbox to a Combobox in the code above, the cut/copy/paste worked so I don't thing you can cut/copy/paste in a Listbox.

Answer (score 0):

`lb.event_generate("<<Cut>>")` is working, in that it's generating the event correct. However, The listbox doesn't have bindings for cut and paste. You'll have to add your own functions to implement cut and paste from a listbox.

For what it's worth, you can see all of the built-in bindings for a widget by calling the `bind_class` method passing only the class name.

```
print(root.bind_class("Listbox"))
```

You can see in the output that `<<Cut>>` and `<<Paste>>` aren't included in the output of that command.

Comment: Yes I see now. When I run the command you suggested it shows <<Cut>> and <<Paste>> in the output. I modified the code to leave only <<Cut>> and <<Paste>> and now it works fine and is really the only two commands I needed.